# Images in Photoshop appear washed out

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile, windows

When I open an image in Photoshop, it appears to be washed out and displays incorrect colors. I am using Windows.

Actual image:
[image: Actual image]

Image displayed in Photoshop:
[image: Image displayed in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Color Management* in Windows (search for it using the Start menu). It should look like this:
[image: Color Management]

Check the box titled *Use my settings for this device*.
[image: Use my settings for this device]

Click *Add...*
[image: Add...]

Select *sRGB IEC-61966-2.1* and hit *OK*.
[image: Associate Color Profile dialogue box]

With this profile selected, click *Set as Default Profile*.

[image: Set as Default Profile]

It should now say *(default)* after the profile name.
[image: sRGB IEC-61966-2.1 (default)]

You're done. Close the window and reopen Photoshop. Your image should now show the proper colors.

Comment: You can also fix this in Photoshop by telling it to use your monitors color space, although there is no 100% grantee there